# Rails + MongoDB not returning all documents in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rails-activerecord

I need all the documents in one of my collections to create association in between my parent model to child. The problem is I only have the string of my ObjectId. So I am finding the object by string and then set via `parent.child = foundObject`. So, to achieve this I created a private method as below, to not to create DB request each time I need that child object.

```
def childs
   @childs ||= Child.all
end
```

But this is not working as expected. When I run `ModelName.all` it returns below result; not all the docs in collection.

```
=> 
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {}
  class:    ModelName
  embedded: false>
```

And this causes my loop to create another DB request each time I try to associate child to parent. I prevent this by using below method.

```
def childs
   @childs ||= Child.all.select { |v| v.id.present? }
end
```

I believe there should be a way of collecting all documents in MongoDB, I know the idea of **Mongoid::Criteria** and what it actually does. But in some case, I need all the objects to be stored in one variable. Do not want to create unwanted DB queries each time I need one specific document in a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to solve this specific problem and I think it's kind of  impossible since MongoDB is not a relational DB It's quite hard to collect information at the same time with querying. What I used is "MongoDB views" and this solved a lot. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) is the docs. There you can read and find yourself an approach to figure out your own problem.